# Spacing form boxes

Tags: html, forms, css

I have a form on my page and i'm trying to give more space between the text boxes.

I tried 'Padding' in all kind of ways but they seem to be grouped together, and whatever i try affect all 4 of them.

- [The page](http://tranceil.co.il/blu4dance/presign/)

If i'm not misstaking this is the Form's CSS for the boxes:

```
.form-inner
{
    /*background:url('../img/content-bg-top.png') no-repeat left top;*/
    min-height:278px;
    margin:-40px 0 0 0;
    padding:72px 72px 21px 36px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    font-size:14px;

    -webkit-text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    -moz-text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`padding` values are for the distance between object's itself and inner content.

You should use `margin` key for each textboxes in the content which is classified as form-inner.

```
.form-inner input[type=text]
{
    margin: 10px 20px;
}
```

Margin defines the distances between object's itself and the other object next to it.

```
margin: [top] [right] [bottom] [left]
```

[image: A nice schematic example]

Comment: Thank you all for your help, Ozkan was first to respond with the correct fix..ill accept this answer

Answer (score 1):

From styl.css (line 317)
`.form-field { ... margin: 0 0 3px }` (bottom margin only...3px)

All 4 of those input boxes are inside containers with `.form-field` class.

One fix:

```
.form-field { margin:0 10px 3px }
.form-field:first-child { margin-left:0 }
```

(that may need to be margin-right. I've never worked with right to left text)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `margin-right` property on `.form-field` class, but remember to set bigger width on form.

Answer (score 1):

I think `.form-inner` is the box around your form. If you want more space between your text boxes, you should style the `.form-field` class.

For example:

```
.form-field {
    padding-right:10px;
}
```